# ROS Kinetic 'catkin_make' fails because PROJECT_NAME is set to Project

Tags: catkin-make, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been using ROS Kinetic for a while,but I do not have very much experience with CMake. Today when I went to make a new catkin workspace following the ROS tutorials page (http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace) I get a CMake Error stating that PROJECT_NAME is set to Project, which is invalid. I have never run into this issue with any of my other work spaces I have created.

I do not want to mess with toplevel.cmake out of fear of screwing up my other work spaces.

Any ideas why this is happening?

The error message:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:91 (message):
  catkin_package() PROJECT_NAME is set to 'Project', which is not a valid
  project name.  You must call project() before calling catkin_package().
```

The CMakeLists.txt file:

```
# toplevel CMakeLists.txt for a catkin workspace
# catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

set(CATKIN_TOPLEVEL TRUE)

# search for catkin within the workspace
set(_cmd "catkin_find_pkg" "catkin" "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
execute_process(COMMAND ${_cmd}
  RESULT_VARIABLE _res
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE _out
  ERROR_VARIABLE _err
  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
  ERROR_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)
if(NOT _res EQUAL 0 AND NOT _res EQUAL 2)
  # searching fot catkin resulted in an error
  string(REPLACE ";" " " _cmd_str "${_cmd}")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Search for 'catkin' in workspace failed (${_cmd_str}): ${_err}")
endif()

# include catkin from workspace or via find_package()
if(_res EQUAL 0)
  set(catkin_EXTRAS_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${_out}/cmake")
  # include all.cmake without add_subdirectory to let it operate in same scope
  include(${catkin_EXTRAS_DIR}/all.cmake NO_POLICY_SCOPE)
  add_subdirectory("${_out}")

else()
  # use either CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH explicitly passed to CMake as a command line argument
  # or CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH from the environment
  if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH)
    if(NOT "$ENV{CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}" STREQUAL "")
      string(REPLACE ":" ";" CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH $ENV{CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
    endif()
  endif()

  # list of catkin workspaces
  set(catkin_search_path "")
  foreach(path ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
    if(EXISTS "${path}/.catkin")
      list(FIND catkin_search_path ${path} _index)
      if(_index EQUAL -1)
        list(APPEND catkin_search_path ${path})
      endif()
    endif()
  endforeach()

  # search for catkin in all workspaces
  set(CATKIN_TOPLEVEL_FIND_PACKAGE TRUE)
  find_package(catkin QUIET
    NO_POLICY_SCOPE
    PATHS ${catkin_search_path}
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH)
  unset(CATKIN_TOPLEVEL_FIND_PACKAGE)

  if(NOT catkin_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "find_package(catkin) failed. catkin was neither found in the workspace nor in the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. One reason may be that no ROS setup.sh was sourced before.")
  endif()
endif()

catkin_workspace()
catkin_package()
```

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327923/ros-kinetic-%27catkin_make%27-fails-because-project_name-is-set-to-project/) by [jaquattro](https://answers.ros.org/users/44018/jaquattro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-07-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-10**:
As @Pulkit123 asks: please show the `CMakeLists.txt` of your ROS package.

**Comment by [jaquattro](https://answers.ros.org/users/44018/jaquattro/) on 2019-07-10**:
I edited the question to show the correct file. However it is a sym link to `toplevel.cmake`, so I think they are the same. Maybe that is the issue? I am new to cmake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So the `CMakeLists.txt` in the directory of your ROS package (ie: **not** the `catkin_ws/src` directory) is a symlink to `/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake`?

If yes: yes, that would be a problem.

---

Edit: Ok. One final check.

Open `$HOME/.bashrc`. Scroll to the end. Make sure there are no `source` lines that source any workspaces. Not even `/opt/ros`. If there are, comment them (`#`) then save the file.

Now open a new terminal and run this:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/abcd/catkin_ws/src
cd /tmp/abcd/catkin_ws
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
catkin_make
```

Does that build successfully?

If it does, again open a new terminal, then:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/efgh/catkin_ws/src
cd /tmp/efgh/catkin_ws/src
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
catkin_create_pkg bar_pkg roscpp
cd /tmp/efgh/catkin_ws
catkin_make
```

Finally, show us the output of:

```
sudo apt install -y tree
tree -L 2 /tmp/efgh/catkin_ws/src
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jaquattro](https://answers.ros.org/users/44018/jaquattro/) on 2019-07-10**:
Thank you! Now to figure out how this happened.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-10**:
If you `unlink` the `CMakeLists.txt` in your package's root, things start working?

**Comment by [jaquattro](https://answers.ros.org/users/44018/jaquattro/) on 2019-07-10**:
If I do that, then `CMakeLists.txt` gets deleted. Just to clarify, the `CMakeLists.txt` file in my new workspace is auto generated, and placed in src, when I run `catkin_make` in the top folder (catkin_ws directory for example). If I `unlink` and then rerun `catkin_make`, the same problem arises.

I am aware I could make my own `CMakeLists.txt`, but I am very confused why following the tutorial to make a new workspace is having this problem.

**Comment by [jaquattro](https://answers.ros.org/users/44018/jaquattro/) on 2019-07-10**:
Apologies, I just realized you asked if it made a sym link to `/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake`. It is actually making a sym link to `/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-10**:
Doesn't matter: the `CMakeLists.txt` of *any* ROS pkg should be an actual file, not a symlink to anything else.

If you create a new workspace, then `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` and then in the `src` space of the new workspace run `catkin_create_pkg foo_pkg roscpp`, it (ie: `foo_pkg`) ends up with a `CMakeLists.txt` that is a symlink to some other file?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-10**:
In which directory do you attempt to run `catkin_make`? In `catkin_ws` or in `catkin_ws/src` or in `catkin_ws/src/foo_pkg/src`?

**Comment by [jaquattro](https://answers.ros.org/users/44018/jaquattro/) on 2019-07-10**:
I run it in `catkin_ws` per [this example](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace) without making `catkin_create_pkg foo_pkg roscpp`. I just tried again after running `catkin_create_pkg foo_pkg roscpp` and I get the same problem when I run `catkin_make` in `catkin_ws`. Does it matter that I am calling it `test_ws`?

**Comment by [jaquattro](https://answers.ros.org/users/44018/jaquattro/) on 2019-07-10**:
Running (after removing all the sourcing from my `.bashrc`)

```
mkdir -p /tmp/abcd/catkin_ws/src
cd /tmp/abcd/catkin_ws
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
catkin_make
```

gives the same error.  :(

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-10**:
Please run the next set of commands and show the output of the `tree` command.

**Comment by [jaquattro](https://answers.ros.org/users/44018/jaquattro/) on 2019-11-04**:
Ultimately, the way I fixed this issue was by reinstalling ROS. I could not accept my own answer, so I leave the solution here and will accept this answer.